# How to enable the iOS spell checker in Mobile Safari?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, spellcheck

The iOS spell checker works for me in all the iOS applications, but it doesn't seem to work for text I type in a text area in Mobile Safari. For instance, spelling errors are underlined in red for emails I type in Mail, but they are not underlined in red in the web-based Gmail. I am not talking about completion feature, but the red underline of misspelled words, which is new with iOS 4, as shown in this screenshot:

[image: iOS 4 spell checking]

How can I get spell checking to work for form fields in Mobile Safari like it works in other applications?

Comment: While you wait for an answer, I would guess there is actually no way to fix this, even with jailbreak. While it should be possible, I don't believe anyone bothered to do it.

Comment: @Cawas, unfortunately, I think you're right ;). So I would suggest that you post this as an answer. This isn't the answer I was hoping for, but it looks like this is this correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's indeed a hole in iphone's safari. I'm not sure if it was always like that or if it's a new undocumented feature that might soon go away.

But meanwhile you can try using [Inspell](http://modmyi.com/cydia/package.php?id=9773) if you're willing to jailbreak. There's just no other way to fix such an issue: it's either apple or cydia.

Another option, if the error occured only in safari, is using [another browser](http://www.opera.com/mobile/). But that doesn't seem to be this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think that has more to do with the way that Google coded their website, than it does with the iPhone itself.

Spell-check works everywhere else on the internet that I have seen while using my phone.

In fact, I just went on my phone and confirmed it works properly on a couple websites including the web version of Facebook.

I would be sending a bug request to Google instead of posting here. That would be much more effective.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: I am not talking about the completion feature, but the spell checker that underlines in red misspelled words. Then when you click on it, the spell checker suggests correct alternatives. This is a new feature in iOS 4. I amended the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

On my iPad Air 2, iOS 9 (it goes back many revisions), I experience the same issue.

I can only report that the situation is slightly different when you are talking mobile Safari on iPad.  No, words are not underlined in red in Safari, quite sadly.

It works exactly as you would want it to in Chrome on the iPad; However the iPhone 6s/ iOS 9 Chrome text entry experience seems to be exactly the same as that of Safari.  I guess that is due to different design paradigms and parameters, small screens, tiny keyboard, etc.  Highly assisted text entry, autocorrection, predictive text, etc. seem to be more important than underlining spelling errors.

Chrome's spell check works just like you would expect, but only when you're using an iPad.  This is what I have found in testing today.

[image]

Comment: Safari on iOS has does not underline misspelled words, the screenshot shows that Chrome does.  This is not a plug, just a fact that you may find helpful.